# I can't get mongodb to start. It opens then shuts down

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb and I am trying to get it up and running.  When I type mongod into the console it starts and then it shuts down again.  Below is the output from my console.

```
2018-03-16T10:54:09.060+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in    initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only    directory: /data/db, terminating
2018-03-16T10:54:09.060+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-03-16T10:54:09.060+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with       code:100
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the error message?

Comment: Is it permission issue?

Comment: Yes, it is a permission issue. Or your `/data/db` resides on a legitimately read-only device, like a CD-ROM (although this one is unlikely)

Comment: It need to run ```sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db``` ?

Comment: Or you need to run mongod under a different user, or *something*. We can't tell you exactly without more information.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following command.

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

and that seemed to do the trick.  Thanks Sergio and Deceze for your comments.